# Como salvar duas variáveis de um JS em sessão do php?

Tags: php, javascript, session

Gostaria de saber, se existe uma forma de salvar essas duas seguintes variáveis.
Segue o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function opcao()
        {
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {   
                var empresa = $('#Empresa option:selected').val();
                $('#Unidades').load('/site/funcoes2.php?emp='+ empresa);
            });
        }
        </script>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function uniopcao()
        {     
            $(document).ready(function () 
            { 
                var unid = $('#Unidades option:selected').val();
                $('#unn').load('/site/tpago.php?uni='+ unid);  
            });
        }
</script>
```

eu gostaria de pegar essas duas variáveis  ( variável "empresas"  que recebe atraves de um onchange a empresa selecionada)  e a (variável "unid" que recebe a unidade escolhida de acordo com a empresa escolhida.
Eu queria atribuir esses valores em uma `SESSION PHP`   como no exemplo abaixo.

```
_SESSION['V1']=  empresa;
_SESSION['V2'] = unid;
```

eu vou utilizar essas duas informações em todo resto do programa  por isso eu gostaria de salva-las.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No seu arquivo "funcoes2.php" adicione a linha:

```
$_SESSION['V1'] =  $_GET['emp'];
```

No seu arquivo "tpago.php" adicione a linha:

```
$_SESSION['V2'] =  $_GET['uni'];
```

Dessa forma, sempre que seu ".load()" carregar a url, a sessão irá setar as variáveis que vc quer.

Answer (score 3):

Vais ter de usa JavaScript para mandares a variável para um novo link: `pagina.php?empresa=1&uni=1`

Depois nessa nova página usas `$_GET`:

```
$_SESSION['V1']= $_GET["empresa"];
$_SESSION['V2']= $_GET["uni"];
```

Comment: obrigado  ambas as respostas me foi valida  agradeço a atenção